# Understanding this use of mean value theorem for vector-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Given a differential curve $\alpha:I\to \mathbb{R}^3$ and a partition $P = \{a=t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n = b\}$ of an interval $[a,b]\subset I$, define $l(\alpha, P) = \sum_i|\alpha(t_i)-\alpha(t_{i-1})|$. I have this question:

[image]

That is, I want to show that the definition of arc lenght is in some sense the limit of the lenghts of inscribed polygons to the curve.

I have this solution:

[image]

But I don't quite understand how they get inequality in red. I know that by mean value theorem for vector-valued functions we have that in each $(t_{i-1}, t_i)$ does exist a $s_i$ such that $|\alpha(t_i) - \alpha(t_{i-1})|\le (t_i - t_{i-1})|\alpha '(s_i)|$ and we can get that sup. But I don't know how they got that inequality.

To me it seems like they used that $0\le A\le B$ implies $|A-x|\le |B - x|$ which clearly isn't true.

Comment: I've never seen the Mean Value inequality stated with a point. I've always seen it as $\|\mathbf f(b)-\mathbf f(a)\|\le \max_{x\in [a,b]}\|\mathbf f'(x)\|(b-a)$ for a $C^1$ function $\mathbf f$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I took this statement from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis' Theorem 5.19.

Comment: Figures. Of course for a $C^1$ function the max occurs at a point. All one cares about is the max. Don’t be misled by Rudin. :) The main point is that we have an upper bound.

Comment: Sure! What I'm caught is that inequality they get from it.

Comment: Please edit to make your question explicit. I thought you were confused about exactly this point.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've edited.

Answer (score 2):

Now that I paid careful attention, you're completely correct. Indeed, the integral will be the sup of the polygonal lengths, provided it exists. Since the problem is assuming the curve is $C^1$, then it does. But you're correct in your assessment of the flaw in the proof.

The standard proof is to show that the length $\ell$, defined as the sup of the polygonal lengths, satisfies both $\ell\le \int_a^b |\alpha'(t)|dt$ and $\ell\ge \int_a^b |\alpha'(t)|dt$.  For this proof, I refer you to p. 7 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).